# How to prepare for trinity's aural exam

Tags: ear-training, exam-grades, trinity

I am going to give my trinity piano grade 5 classical and jazz exam later this year in October, one of my supporting tests is aural. Now, there are websites and apps that I found online which can help me with cadences, and intervals. However, for the other components, such as identifying the changing tonality of a piece, changes in pitch and rhythm(where an examiner plays a melody twice but the second time there's a change in pitch and rhythm, the student must identify the changes), and time signature identification, I wasn't able to find any good resources to help me prepare. Could anyone please help me by giving me methods or resources to prepare for these aspects of the exam too. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: An obvious solution is to visit a teacher a few times, who is conversant with the exam system. Well worth while anyhow, before taking a grade exam (several months prior) to make sure you're on the right tracks with the rest of the syllabus.